# MS Office applications (ALL!) always on top

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, always-on-top

I've searched a while and seen specific Add-on or taskbar lock/unlock fixes for Excel, Word, and Outlook, but I've having the same issue with the windows always staying on top for ALL programs.  This leads me to think it's not app-specific, but some global or environment variable issue.  Can anyone confirm and/or help with this? Running Win 7 with Office 2013 for reference.

EDIT:  Now Win Photo Viewer is doing it too, something graphics related?  I cannot even force another window of any type over it.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer to see if the issue persists?